# Is it possible to know when ReSharper's test runner is building my project?

Tags: msbuild, build-process, nunit, resharper

I'm trying to use the MSBuild NUnit community task to force tests to run on each build, but I now see that when I use ReSharper's test runner and it builds the project I'm running the tests twice.  It works but is not really desirable.

Does anyone know of a variable or condition I can check within MSBuild so that I can skip the community task if I know the test runner is going to execute the tests anyway?

Note: I'm using VS2008 and the MSBuild script is integrated with the solution/project files.  I want the best of all worlds.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, plus command-line, plus CI server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question on the [Resharper community forums](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5229453) and although I didn't get a direct yes or no to my question, I interpreted the answer to be no.  If anyone wants to chime in with a confirmed yes or no, it would set my mind at ease.

I decided I could work around my problem by creating a solution configuration called `DebugResharperTest` and I choose that config when I want to use the Resharper test runner.  That configuration name variable will keep the build from kicking off the NUnit msbuild task.

Answer (score 2):

When building in Visual Studio MSBuild defines an extra property that you can use to disable the nUnit Task.

```
<NUnit Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'"
    ...other props 
    />
```

Comment: I hadn't seen that extra property.  Thanks.  Too bad resharper doesn't have a way to turn that property to false when it starts a build.